# changing background image multiple times with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

Simply trying to cycle through 3 images by clicking on them.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleImages(obj) {
if(obj.style.backgroundImage == "url('images/none.jpg')") {
    obj.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/iPhoneImage-300x300.jpg')";
}
else if(obj.style.backgroundImage == "url('images/iPhoneImage-300x300.jpg')"){
    obj.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/smartphoneImage-300x300.jpg')";
}
else if(obj.style.backgroundImage == "url('images/smartphoneImage-300x300.jpg')"){
obj.style.backgroundColor = "url('images/none.jpg')";
}
}

 </script>

<div onclick="toggleImages(this);" id="arrow1" style="background-image:url(images/none.jpg); display:block; width:300px; height:300px"></div>
```

It works if I change the background color with no image but not the background image which makes me think it has to do with the url.

thanks
for the help

Comment: give it a try with classes instead just updating background-image or use background-position with multiple image

Comment: This one worked! Thanks GCyrillus!

Answer (score 0):

My javascript console prints **url("images/none.jpg")** with double quotes and you are checking with single, you must use something other to check it. One way (not so smart) is this:

```
   function toggleImages(obj) {
    var tmp=obj.style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\(('|")/,'').replace(/('|")\)/,'')
    if(tmp == "images/none.jpg") {
        obj.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/iPhoneImage-300x300.jpg')";
    }else if(tmp == "images/iPhoneImage-300x300.jpg"){
        obj.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/smartphoneImage-300x300.jpg')";
    }else if(tmp == "images/smartphoneImage-300x300.jpg"){
        obj.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/none.jpg')";
    }
    console.log(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the single and double quotes.
Also note that your code has one obj.style.backgroundColor which should be obj.style.backgroundImage.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleImages(obj) {
if(obj.style.backgroundImage == 'url("images/none.jpg")') {
    obj.style.backgroundImage = 'url("images/iPhoneImage-300x300.jpg")';
}
else if(obj.style.backgroundImage == 'url("images/iPhoneImage-300x300.jpg")'){
    obj.style.backgroundImage = 'url("images/smartphoneImage-300x300.jpg")';
}
else if(obj.style.backgroundImage == 'url("images/smartphoneImage-300x300.jpg")'){
obj.style.backgroundImage = 'url("images/none.jpg")';
}
}

 </script>

<div onclick="toggleImages(this);" id="arrow1" style="background-image:url(images/none.jpg); display:block; width:300px; height:300px"></div>
```